# How to compile a pure native executable for rooted Android

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I'm working on a rooted Android 2.3.
In my application, using jni mechanism I call a native (c/c++) function that needs root permissions to operate, thats why it always fails (even though my phone is rooted - because the specific process/app need to grant the root permission) .

I want to move that function to an external executable that will run on the linux by the command "sudo exec_name" that I will run from java (`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo ...")`;)

So

1) How can I compile a native executable? (not a library as usual [.so])

2) After I have a stand alone executable, where in the system I have to put it and with what permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile a native executable use `include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)` instead of `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)`. There is an example in `NDK` called `test-libstdc++` which show how to build the simplest native executable.

Then you need to put it in executable location like `/data/local` and call `chmod 777` in order to make it executable. After that you can run it via shell.

> > I want to move that function to an external executable that will run on the linux by the command "sudo exec_name" that I will run from java (Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo ...");)

In this case your workflow will look like this:

- You compile your code into native executable file and put it in app assets
- At start you need to copy yoru executable file from assets to the `/system/bin`
- Allow to run it using `chmod 777`
- Actually run your executable

The first three points should be done only once.